# error while importing MySQL from flask_mysqldb in python 2.7.10

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Recently I've been working on flask. I'm getting an error while importing MySQL.

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

I spend most of day yesterday, trying different solution from stack overflow to get it worked but nothing is working, So I'm posting a new question.

```
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Users/abhishek/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
    File "/Users/abhishek/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/abhishek/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
    Referenced from: /Users/abhishek/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/_mysql.so
    Reason: image not found
```

I'm Working on MacOS Mojave.

Installed flask

```
pip install flask
```

Installed flask-mysqldb

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

Installed MySQL from [macOS 10.13 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archiv](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Comment: Have you considered using homebrew to install a more current version of Python? Not sure if that is causing your specific problem, but the OS X built in Python is several versions back (2.7.15 is the current Python2 version as I write this).

Comment: yeah I tried that but still getting the same error